# What is wrong with my logic my button only changes once and the onclick function stops?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a button to switch between F and C each time i do the click but when i click the button a third time it just doesn't work even though i set back the class to `.temp`.

```
$(".temp").click(function() {
  $('#temperature').empty();
  $("#temperature").append(temp.main.temp + " <a class='temper' href='#'>C</a>");

  $(".temper").click(function() {
    $('#temperature').empty();
    $('#temperature').append(data.main.temp +" <a class='temp' href='#'>F</a>");
  });  
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Thanks! T.J.Crowder for banning me from asking any more questions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this line:

```
$("#temperature").append(temp.main.temp + " <a class='temper' href='#'>C</a>");
```

you are adding some html content dynamically.

So use:

```
$(document).on('click', '.temper', function(){

});
```

instead of static listener i.e.

```
$(".temper").click()
```

because this kind of listener works for static html only.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works now i spent atleast 4 hours trying to get it to work

Comment: @Chris use `.bind` `$(document).bind('click', '.temper', function(){...})`

Comment: Just a query Mayank. Should you not search for the duplicate as this is an obvious question?

Comment: @Rajesh: will keep thin in mind for future.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are about to use live jquery event, this can help :

```
$(document).on("click", ".temp", function() {});
$(document).on("click", ".temper", function() {});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Kanzari/n38xs8sn/2/

Answer (score 0):

Check this Fiddle it's working example but missing this part (temp.main.temp):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$(document).on("click", ".temp", function() {
    $('#temperature').empty();
  $("#temperature").append(" <a class='temper' href='#'>C</a>");
});
$(document).on("click", ".temper", function() {
$('#temperature').empty();
  $("#temperature").append(" <a class='temp' href='#'>F</a>");
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Kanzari/n38xs8sn/2/

Answer (score -1):

why you wrote the code of temper.click inside the temp.click function?
correct it as :

```
$(".temp").click(function(){

  $('#temperature').empty();
  $("#temperature").append(temp.main.temp+" <a class='temper' href='#'>C</a>");
});


$(".temper").click(function(){

   $('#temperature').empty();
   $('#temperature').append(data.main.temp+" <a class='temp' href='#'>F</a>"  );
});
```

Comment: This will not work. You will have to use delegates to handle it